# Why doesn't prompt for input in a batch file allow for a DASH character?

Tags: sql-server-2005, batch-file

I have this simple little batch file program that I wrote but it fails if I enter a database name that contains a "-" character.   Im not exactly sure why but I wish I could figure out a way around this?

```
:: open DB batch file
@echo off
:: starts Sql Server Management Studio Express 2005
:: and opens it to a specific database with query
:: window already open

cls

:SHOWDBNAMES
echo Database names detected on this system:
echo.
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE" -h-1 -S . -E -Q "SELECT CAST(name AS VARCHAR(30)) FROM sysdatabases"

@echo.
set DBNAME=
set /P DBNAME=What database name would you like to open (choose from list)? 

if "%DBNAME%" == "" (
  echo.
  echo I don't recognize your selection. Try again.
  goto SELECTDB
)

:SHOWTABLES
cls
echo.
echo Tables that you can query from %DBNAME% are:
echo.
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE" -h-1 -S . -E -Q "use [%DBNAME%];SELECT CAST(name AS VARCHAR(30)) FROM sys.Tables ORDER BY name"
echo.

:RUNIT
sqlwb.exe -nosplash -S . -E -d %DBNAME%

pause
:EOF
```

Comment: i think its possible that the "-" char is throwing off osql.exe ,which expects them to be argument flags. dont know how to get around it.  the double quotes around the sql string dont seem to protect osql from thinking its a new arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing the database name in square brackets:

`[database-name]`

**EDIT**

The following should work - you need to quote the database name in the call to sqlwb.exe:

```
:SHOWTABLES
cls
echo.
echo Tables that you can query from %DBNAME% are:
echo.
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE" -h-1 -S . -E -Q "SELECT CAST(name AS VARCHAR(30)) FROM [%DBNAME%].sys.Tables ORDER BY name"
echo.

:RUNIT
sqlwb.exe -nosplash -S . -E -d "%DBNAME%"
```

I've got to ask though - what's the point of this script? The built-in SSMS object explorer gives you all this information for free.

Also, your script doesn't take account of SQL server instances other than the default - SQL Server Express is installed as `<machine_name>\SQLEXPRESS` by default.

Comment: tried it.  doesn't solve the problem with the sys.Tables query.   I tried "use [database-name]; select ....."

Comment: i think OSQL.exe , being a .exe program, thinks that all "-" chars means a new argument to the executable.  thats my best guess.

Comment: @djangofan - I've updated my answer with an edit which should work.

Comment: thanks. that worked.  the reason for the script is that is a few seconds faster than opening SSSME and then clicking through the "Connect Object Explorer".  This script will save me 5+ seconds for each time I want to open SSSME.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try an underscore (_)?

Comment: I want my script to support all conditions including a '-' character.

Answer (score 0):

Is it failing on the `sqlwb.exe` line when the dash is the first letter in the database name?  If so, your problem is that `sqlwb` is misinterpreting the database name as a command line option.  There should be some way to make it not do that; check the manual.

Comment: no, it fails on the sys.Tables query only.  everywhere else it works.